# Improper priors for bayesian multivariate generalized linear models in R

Tags: r, bayesian, mcmc, multivariate-testing

I am trying to run a bayesian multivariate generalized linear model with `OFT1`, `MIS1`, `wt`, and `g.rate` as the response variables, `grid`, `collar`, `sex`, `fieldBirthDate`, and `trialnumber` as the predictor variables, and `sq_id` as the random effect.

My data looks like this:

```
sq_id sex grid trialnumber collar       OFT1        MIS1 fieldBirthDate          wt      g.rate
22640   F   KL           2      Y -2.1947851  0.08686934      -2.036220  2.04349949 0.202092846
22640   F   KL           1      Y  0.7661517  2.65544077      -2.036220 -0.09300674 0.546493570
22641   F   KL           1      Y  0.9689955  1.38944543      -2.036220  0.04942701 0.582793646
22653   F   SU           1      Y -2.1524967  1.03831742      -1.665209  0.44824150 0.691384500
22657   M   KL           1      N  1.0918323 -2.03883227      -1.788879 -0.40636099 0.008592439
22657   M   KL           2      N  3.1173521 -2.34449199      -1.788879  2.44231398 0.249185968
```

And, is available [here](https://figshare.com/s/ace5b44bc12394a7c46d) (this link is no longer active as of 06/22/19). The R package used was `MCMCglmm`.

I start by stating my prior:

```
#inverse whishart prior
prior.miw<-list(R=list(V=diag(4), nu=0.002), 
            G=list(G1=list(V=diag(4), 
            nu=0.002,   
            alpha.mu=c(0,0,0,0), 
            alpha.V=diag(4)*1000)))
```

Then my model:

```
mod.1 <- MCMCglmm(
    cbind(OFT1, MIS1, wt, g.rate) ~ (trait-1):grid + (trait-1):collar + (trait-1):sex + (trait-1):fieldBirthDate + (trait-1):trialnumber,
    random = ~us(trait):sq_id,
    rcov = ~us(trait):units, #allows for trait to have different residuals
    family = c("gaussian", "gaussian", "gaussian", "gaussian"), #state response variables distributions
    data=multi_data, 
    prior = prior.miw, 
    verbose = FALSE, 
    nitt=103000, #number of iterations
    thin=100, #the interval at which the Markov chain is stored
    burnin=3000) #number of iterations before samples are stored
```

But, I then get the following two errors (which change each time I run my code):

> G-structure 1 is ill-conditioned: use proper priors if you haven't or rescale data if you have

and

> ill-conditioned cross-product: can't form Cholesky factor

I made sure to scale my variables properly (mean centered and standardized) and I have tried other priors such as the inverse gamma prior (that works). However, I want to use the inverse whishart prior. If I modify my inverse whishart prior code by removing the `alpha.mu` and `alpha.V` functions from it, like so:

```
prior.miw<-list(R=list(V=diag(4), nu=0.002), 
            G=list(G1=list(V=diag(4), 
            nu=0.002)))
```

my multivariate model runs. But, I would like to keep `alpha.mu` and `alpha.V` in my prior.

I have two questions:

1. Why am I getting these errors? (i.e. why is my inverse whishart prior causing me this issue as I've currently written it?)
2. What is the proper inverse whishart prior with `alpha.mu` and `alpha.V` functions in it?

Any suggestions or ideas would be much appreciated!